# libwebsockets throws CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR: Unable to connect when performing Ping operation

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I have sort of hit a dead end. Can someone please help.
I have never used libwebsockets before. I have an RPI4(Installed Ubuntu 22.04), where my code is running which tries to ping my Laptop(Windows 10). Both are on same Wi-Fi network. I am able to Ping each other through command prompt, however through code it throws an error CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR.
Same code works properly on Ubuntu 20.04 running on x86_64 Virtual Box.
However it does not work when we run it on an RPI4.
Here's the error log:

```
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0612] N: lws_create_context: LWS: 4.3.99-v4.3.0-275-gec6d5ac6, NET CLI SRV H1 H2 WS SS-JSON-POL ConMon IPv6-absent
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0716] N: __lws_lc_tag:  ++ [wsi|0|pipe] (1)
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0758] N: __lws_lc_tag:  ++ [vh|0|netlink] (1)
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0781] N: __lws_lc_tag:  ++ [vh|1|default||-1] (2)
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0845] N: lws_tls_client_create_vhost_context: doing cert filepath
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0895] N: HttpPing: connecting to 192.168.1.4:7778
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0905] N: __lws_lc_tag:  ++ [wsicli|0|GET/h1/default/192.168.1.4] (1)
[2022/12/18 14:52:36:0907] N: [wsicli|0|GET/h1/default/192.168.1.4]: lws_client_connect_3_connect: trying 192.168.1.4
CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR: Unable to connect
[2022/12/18 14:52:38:0927] N: __lws_lc_untag:  -- [wsicli|0|GET/h1/default/192.168.1.4] (0) 2.002s
[2022/12/18 14:52:38:0932] N: __lws_lc_untag:  -- [wsi|0|pipe] (0) 2.021s
[2022/12/18 14:52:38:0933] N: __lws_lc_untag:  -- [vh|0|netlink] (1) 2.017s
[2022/12/18 14:52:38:0934] N: __lws_lc_untag:  -- [vh|1|default||-1] (0) 2.015s
```

Things tried:

1. Disabled IPV6 while compiling libwebsockets by using the command -> cmake .. -DLWS_IPV6=OFF
2. Turned off Firewall on ubuntu